# Java List is an interface with implemented methods?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, interface, implements

Java Lists (also Collection) have method implementations (`add()`,`get()`) so how can they be INTERFACES?
I would expect:

```
List <Integer> nums = ArrayList <Integer>();
nums.add(5);
```

that the above code would be in error since add() should be implemented in ArrayList not List(being an interface)  But that is not the case, the code works fine.
Can someone explain this?

Comment: "*Lists (also Collection) have method implementations (`add()`,`get()`)*" could you show them to us (BTW, declaration != implementation)? Also since Java 8 interfaces can have some [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) but in `List` `add()` and `get()` is not one of them.

Comment: You seem confused as to what an interface actually is.

Comment: List has no implementations. Otherwise you could write List <Integer> nums = List <Integer>(); instead (which would not work).

Comment: @DuKes0mE Since Java 8 List has few implemented methods like [`sort(Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) so we no longer need to use `Collections.sort(list,Comparator)` but since it is still only interface it is possible that it can have other unimplemented methods, so we still can't initialize it via `new List`.

Answer (score 3):

This is just polymorphism in action. An `ArrayList` is-a `List`, and can therefore be assigned to a variable of type `List`.

The interface defines the contract of any class that implements it. It doesn't implement the methods (caveat: this is changing as of Java 8).

The variable `nums` is a `List`, but its concrete type is an `ArrayList` due to the assignment. The runtime treats it as polymorphic, and therefore the runtime *dynamically binds* to the `add` on the actual type that is stored in `nums`: i.e. it calls the `add` method on `ArrayList`.

I recommend reading [The Java Tutorials > Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), and the pages on Interfaces in the same section.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be somewhat confused as to what an `interface` is, or at least how you use them. `interface` in Java defines a set of method signatures that any class which `implements` the interface must provide (or else be `abstract`). `ArrayList` is one such class which implements the `List` interface. When you do the following:

```
List<Integer> nums = ArrayList<Integer> ()
```

You are creating an instance of `ArrayList`, which implements all the methods of `List`, and assigning it to a variable which can hold any object that implements `List`. This means that when using `nums`, you can only access methods exposed by `List`. However, the methods actually being *called* are those of `ArrayList`.

Java encourages using `interfaces` because they aren't bound to a particular inheritance chain. Consider the following method signatures:

```
public <T> void foo(List<T> input)
public <T> void bar(ArrayList<T> input)
```

The `foo` method can take anything that implements `List`; this could be one of the standard library objects, like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, or it could be a user-defined class that provides completely different functionality in addition to the standard `List` operations. This makes it much more flexible; `foo` is simply stating that expects an object that looks and acts like a `List`, but doesn't care what that object is.

The `bar` method, on the other hand, uses `ArrayList` directly. If later on you realize you want to use a different collection, you're stuck, because you can only use an `ArrayList` or a class which extends `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

An interface is a contract, and there is guaranteed to be some concrete implementation behind it. For example, you could use

```
List<Integer> nums = ArrayList<>();
```

**or**

```
List<Integer> nums = LinkedList<>();
```

They differ in terms of their internal implementation (but both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` fulfil the contract specified by the `List` interface). Finally, in Java 8+ `interface`(s) can have [default methods](http://www.journaldev.com/2752/java-8-interface-changes-static-methods-default-methods-functional-interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

`implements List` is a promise that the class has all the methods declared in the interface `List`. If all you need from an object is the `List` methods, it does not matter which class it actually is, as long as that class implements `List`.

`List nums = new ArrayList ();` declares `nums` to be a `List` reference. That means that any object it ever points to must be an instance of a class that implements `List`, and therefore has all the methods that `List` declares.

`nums.add(5);` uses the `add` method that any object `nums` references must supply, because it must implement `List`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here(OpenJDK source code): http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/List.java.html

List is an interface with **no** implementation. You need to declare an ArrayList or another List which implements this interface

Comment: You don't need to look at the source code to see that. The Javadc tells you.

Comment: @EJP That is true. I wasn't sure at which point the OP claimed that List had an actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should study about inheritance. List is an interface that does not contain any implementation. But ArrayList contains all implementations of List interface.

When you call nums.add(5) you see List.add() method is being called but actually it calls ArrayList.add(5) method in background. That is the secret of Inheritance

Check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

Body of method is loaded dynamically (at runtime) based on actual type of object held by reference (it is called [late or dynamic binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding)), so for code

```
List <Integer> nums = ArrayList <Integer>();
```

actual object in `nums` reference would be instance of `ArrayList` class, so code of `add/get` would be loaded from `ArrayList`.

`List` doesn't actually have implementation of `get()` method, but calling

```
nums.add(5);
```

it is not a problem for compiler, because it knows that `ArrayList` will contain some implementation for all *abstract* (without body) methods from `List` interface.